# Pressing enter to create a labeled textbox using html/css/js (screenshot attached)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'll attach screenshots first for what I'm trying to replicate.

First, you have a form [image: basic form]

Then, you enter some text [image]

And when you press then 'enter' key, you end up with this [image]

I have absolutely no idea where to start when trying to create a form that replicates this functionality. Would I have to use Javascript to add a listener for the 'enter' key and change the css?

I am unsure how to search for the functionality either, and would really appreciate if anybody could give some insight, and maybe a tutorial or template anywhere. I spent hours googling to no avail..

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to have the same functionality a while back and wrote it from scratch... then to find it's included in a bootstrap/jQuery plugin. Read about the "tags" here

[Bootstrap Tag functionality Examples](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

This should be exactly what you are looking for.